# unity2d button collider collide with border when character moves

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a button that is clickable during the game playing. As I want the button have a fixed position in the main camera, I made both the main camera and the button children of the player gameObject so that the camera will follow the character while jumping or moving, everything works fine but there also a border colliders which will prevent the character moving out of the playing area. But then the collider of the button which was made intend to make the button clickable will also collide with the border which will prevent the character moving right forward. If we set the collider of the button a trigger, it seems that the button will be triggered wherever I click the mouse on the screen, that's not what I wanted.

I know maybe I could prevent this by checking if the collided object is the button or the character, but is there a better way to do that? Thanks.

[image: demostration]

Comment: So the button as I understand the button has a fixed position with the camera and it is always in the same place in the screen?

Comment: yes, @IgnacioAlorre that is what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a 2D platform game, I would add a 2D user interface in a canvas over the "map" (the layer where you have the gameobjects like the character, platforms, enemies...). So the button will be always in the same place of the screen and will never collide with any gameobject of the game.

You make take some ideas from here: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-events-and-event-triggers

Comment: thanks for answering, but will that layer stick with the camera while the camera moves?

Comment: Yes, actually it will cover the whole screen, it will not linked with the camera. That option also exist for 3D games. For example in a FPS where there is a character moving around a map, you can add this canvas to display information like: amount of life, bullets, life... You can see how they use it in this tutorial: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/health-hud

Comment: @armnostrong Is this solution suitable for you or should we try to find someting else? Im sure there are other options, but I thing this is the best one.

Comment: hmm... I am trying this, while trying this I find the canvas contains the ui-button is tremendously big than the game area that the camera contains. Not sure about the relation about Unity3d unit and the real pixels. thanks for your answer and will accept this after the trying.

Comment: Dont worry about that, it just have a different scale so it is easier to distinguish. No matter how big it looks in the scene, once you run the game the Canvas will match with the size of your screen.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out Ignacio, just found it hard to manipulate the element on the canvas together with the gameObject as they have different scales, but if you are meeting the same issue, then I know it's not my fault, we just have to suffer that, cheers! :-D

Answer (score 2):

Try use new UI in Unity may it fix your issue:

```
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-button
```